# Что быстрее - System.currentTimeMillis() или Date().getTime()?

Tags: java, android, время, datetime, производительность

Что быстрее -  `System.currentTimeMillis()` или `Date().getTime()`?

Comment: А если измерить?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` не создает объекта. а `Date().getTime()` создает. разница только в этом. Там есть маленькое время где нужно создать объект. из этого многие советуют использовать `System.currentTimeMillis() `

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) чуть быстрее, чем [`Date().getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29):

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    System.currentTimeMillis();
}
System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));


t = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    new Date().getTime();
}
System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
```

Результат:

```
Elapsed: 11623
Elapsed: 11713
```

---

А причина этого очень проста, если посмотреть на [исходники](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#l163), то видно, что в конструкторе `Date` вызывается `System.currentTimeMillis()` (об этом [тут писали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506164/201445)):

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Comment: Практически без разницы, создание объекта обходится очень дешево.

Comment: @RomanC зависимость от загрузки системы может повлиять в будущем

Comment: @Insider Судя по коду, загрузка будет максимальная причем на одно ядро, хотя сам фактор загрузки весьма важный, так как может повлиять на результаты вычислений, для того чтобы правильно распределить загрузку надо запускать тесты на разных процессорах/ядрах, при относительной степени загрузки, а не так как сейчас.

Answer (score 26):

Теоретически `System.currentTimeMillis()` будет быстрей за счёт того, что не создается новый обьект `new Date()`, который все равно вызывает `System.currentTimeMillis()`, но разница будет ничтожна.

Answer (score 20):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` - быстрее, просто потому, что new Date() само вызывает эту функцию. Можете посмотреть это в реализации для [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#l163). Так же можете посмотреть похожий [вопрос на SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368094/system-currenttimemillis-vs-new-date-vs-calendar-getinstance-gettime).